# Removing text contained within brackets

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, while-loop, readline

I am trying to write a program that cleans up a text file; specifically, I am trying to clean up a copy of Shakespeare's "A Midsummer's Night Dream". I am trying to write a code that will eliminate the stage directions from the script, so that this text:

> THESEUS Go, bid the huntsmen wake them with their horns.
>
> [Horns, and shout within. DEMETRIUS, LYSANDER,HERMIA, and HELENA awake
>
> and start up.]
>
> Good-morrow, friends. Saint Valentine is past; Begin these wood-birds
>   but to couple now?
>
> LYSANDER Pardon, my lord.
>
> [He and the rest kneel to THESEUS.]
>
> THESEUS
>
> I pray you all, stand up. I know you two are rival enemies; How comes this gentle concord in the world, That hatred is so
>   far from jealousy To sleep by hate, and fear no enmity?

Becomes this text:

> THESEUS Go, bid the huntsmen wake them with their horns.
>
> Good-morrow, friends. Saint Valentine is past; Begin these wood-birds
>   but to couple now?
>
> LYSANDER Pardon, my lord.
>
> THESEUS
>
> I pray you all, stand up. I know you two are rival enemies; How comes this gentle concord in the world, That hatred is so
>   far from jealousy To sleep by hate, and fear no enmity?

This is the code I've written, but it's getting hung up, on the while loop I'm assuming. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def cleanDirections(inFilename, outFilename):
    inFile = open(inFilename, "r")
    outFile = open(outFilename, "w")

    line = inFile.readline()

    while line != "":

        if line.startswith("[") == True:
            if line.endswith("]") == True:
                line = inFile.readline()
            else:
                while line.endswith("]") == False:
                    line = inFile.readline()
            line = inFile.readline()

        else:
            outFile.write(line)
            line = inFile.readline()
```

Also: If help could be provided in this kind syntax, that would be great. I am still learning, and so I don't know more advanced python yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple approach, making lots of assumptions, like:

1. Only "[" in the first column is significant.
2. "[" and "]" don't nest - there's only 1 level of square bracket.
3. There's nothing on a line (except perhaps whitespace) following a "]". Anything following "]" will be lost.

If you can live with those:

```
inFile = open(inFilename, "r")
outFile = open(outFilename, "w")
skipping = False
for line in infile:
    if skipping:
        # don't print this line no matter what,
        # hut stop skipping if "]" in line
        if "]" in line:
            skipping = False
    elif line.startswith("["):
        # don't print this line either no matter what,
        # and start skipping if "]" _not_ in the line
        skipping = "]" not in line
    else:
        outfile.write(line)
infile.close()
outfile.close()
if skipping:
    raise ValueError("hit end of file with unclosed '['!")
```

If you can't live with those restrictions, then it gets more complicated ;-)

Comment: You like it because it's a lot like your code - LOL ;-) But I applaud your desire to avoid regexps here - they can be very powerful, but also very obscure. The logic here is easily coded without them.

Comment: with many more lines than with them. This can be done in one line using a regex.

Comment: @Tommy, there are several semantic differences between this code and your 1-liner. For an example that matters, this code kills the newline at the end of a line containing a closing ']' - your regexp 1-liner does not. It's clear that the OP does *not* want "extra" newlines left over. For another, this code scales without change to files too large to fit in RAM - and again the 1-liner does not. I'll leave it to you to find other differences. Brevity is not the same as clarity. If you don't believe that, note that the OP actually understands *this* code ;-)

Comment: "I don't want to learn the basics of RE" is not a good excuse to ignore the best solution for the problem at hand. The OP wants to understand code without learning tools/skills that could better solve the job, and IMO, that is not "readability" but "laziness".  The OP did not mention files that cannot fit into RAM; he mentioned an entire book in txt which I guarantee is a few MB at most. Do you know how big of a book a GB of text is? Not even War and Peace comes close. Also, regarding the newline, you are correct, but the regex is easily retrofit.

Comment: I even tried to explain the regex as much as possible so that it is not obscure.

Comment: @Tommy, give it a rest. The problem the OP wanted to solve is trivial. Why should they bother to learn REs just for this? They have a problem to solve, and it's *very easily* solved without RE. From Jamie Zawinski (an early Netscape developer): "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.'  Now they have two problems." <0.4 wink>.

Comment: Just a note @Tommy, I do want to learn the basics of regex, but not wanting to do that at the moment isn't "laziness", but practicality. I'm still learning python, and mastering what I've learned and do know before I move on to something more complicated seems both practical and beneficial. I appreciate your help, but I never said I don't want to learn the basics, I just said I don't want to learn them _until_ I master what I know. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: They should not bother to learn REs just for this. They should learn REs to solve this and the next 100 problems that require searching text for arbitrary patterns. That is what regex does/was built for. I agree people abuse regex in situations where they shouldn't, but this is not one of them. You taught a man to catch this particular fish. I taught the man to catch infinite similar fish. Your solution is not forgiving of input either. What if [STUFF] occurs within a line, and the first character of that line is not "["? Mine needs only assumption #2; more applicable to more inputs.

Comment: Which is another semantic difference, and you have no basis for proclaiming that '[` *anywhere* in a line should mark text to be deleted.  That the OP's *original code* used `.startswith()` implied that the column position *was* significant. You're solving a different problem than the one stated. Oh well, we're never going to agree on this, so I'll leave the last rant to you ;-)

Comment: His code is also not forgiving of input errors lol. I'm going to download shakespeare and find a [...] that comes after some whitespace or erroneously put into the middle of a line to prove my point if I have to!

Comment: lol, in this one (http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=midsummer&Scope=entire&pleasewait=1&msg=pl), there are several [EXIT....] after whitespace due to indentation, hence line does not start with '['.

Answer (score 2):

Since your brackets span multiple lines, then you cannot do this line by line. Use:

```
text = inFile.readLines()
text = re.sub("\[[^\]]*\]","",text) #will kill any [STUFF]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `re`:

```
while "[" in string:
    string=string.replace(string[string.find("["):string.find("]")+1],"")
```

You have to read all file to `string` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to python, though I did this in a C-Like way. It's simple to understand:)

```
newFile = open('out.txt', 'w')

inStageDirections = False

with open('sp.txt') as f:
    for c in f.read():
        if inStageDirections is False and c == '[':
            inStageDirections = True
        elif inStageDirections is True and c == ']':
            inStageDirections = False
            continue

        if not inStageDirections:
            newFile.write(c)

        if inStageDirections:
            pass
```

It parses the file char by char, and sets a `inStageDirections` when you counter `[` to make sure the following text won't be written in the new file. Though I strongly recommend you using regexps to finish this job, since it's more faster and more elegant.